# Chown a specific folder without root privilleges

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, file-permissions

I need to chown a file to some other user, and make sure it is unreadable again. Sounds complicated but it will be mainly look like this:

```
cd /readonly
wget ...myfile
cd /workdir
chmod -R 444 /readonly
chown -R anotheruser /readonly

ls /readonly # OK
echo 123 > /readonly/newfile # Should not be allowed
cat /readonly/myfile # OK
chown 777 /readonly # Should not be allowed
```

In SunOS I saw something similar to this, I remember not being able to delete the disowned files by Apache, but I could not find something similar to this in Linux, as chmod requires root privilleges.

The reason I need this, I will fetch some files from web, make sure they will be unchangable by the rest of the script, only root can change it. The script can not definetely run as root.

Comment: Maybe http://unix.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask this question

Comment: You can try to use `chattr +i` if your filesystem supports it.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27350/why-cant-a-normal-user-chown-a-file

Answer (score 1):

On many *nixes (Linux, at the very least), this will be impossible.
`chown` is a privilege restricted to root, since otherwise you could pawn off your files on other users to avoid quota restrictions.
In a related case, it would also pose something of a semantic problem if arbitrary users could `chown` files to themselves to gain access.

More precisely, you can `chown` files that you own to change their group ownership information, but you can only change user ownership if you are root.

In any case, `chown` is the wrong hammer for this particular nail.
`chmod`, which you are already using, is the correct way to make a file read-only within a script.
The `chmod 444` that you are already doing will protect against accidental modifications to the files.
You cannot "freeze" or otherwise render permissions static as a Unix/Linux user without elevating to root privileges (at which point, you can `chown` them to `root:root` and no one other than root can change permissions or ownership on them).

In terms of script design, you should not need to be more restrictive than this.
If your script is haphazardly `chmod`ing or `rm -f`ing files, then you have much more serious correctness problems to worry about than ensuring that the downloaded data is safe and sound.

Comment: *"You cannot "freeze" or otherwise render permissions static as a Unix/Linux user without elevating to root privileges"* `chattr +i myfile` will mark a file as immutable. I'm not sure whether this freezes permissions, too, but one can no longer write to the file. This can only be done by root: I can't set -/+i without root.

Comment: @Luc the "immutable" file attribute does prevent permissions changes, but it's a lot more obscure than just changing ownership to root. It also prevents a number of other activities, so it's a lot more limiting than a change of ownership.